# Does standalone single quotes formatter exist for python?

Tags: python, pycharm

**Problem**:
I need to use single quotes formatter for Python. **ONLY** this feature.

My tries to find a tool for this goal.
Test code example:
test.py

```
print("start")
o_data = {
    "status": False,
    "message": "some str",
    "something": ""
}
print(f"status of o_data is '{o_data['status']}'")
```

[axblack](https://pypi.org/project/axblack/) formatted to:

```
print('start')
o_data = {'status': False, 'message': 'some str', 'something': ''}
print(f"status of o_data is '{o_data['status']}'")
```

[oitnb](https://pypi.org/project/oitnb/) formatted to:

```
print('start')
o_data = {'status': False, 'message': 'some str', 'something': ""}
print(f"status of o_data is '{o_data['status']}'")
```

I didn't find single quotes formatting in setting PyCharm also.

I expect formatting result:

```
print('start')
o_data = {
    'status': False,
    'message': 'some str',
    'something': ''
}
print(f"status of o_data is '{o_data['status']}'")
```

I don't need other formatting features as format Dict to one line and so on, **only** double quotes to single quotes.

Maybe somebody knows a tool (IDE extension and etc.) to do this?

Comment: can't you use `search and replace` ? you can find it in any editor. OR maybe you should try to write this function with Python.

Comment: @furas How does "search and replace" work for this line from example print(f"status of o_data is '{o_data['status']}'")?

Comment: axblack works well, but is there a way to disable other features except single-quotes formating?

Comment: in some editors you can select some lines and it will search and replace only in these lines.

Comment: did you check documentation for `axblack` ?

Comment: @furas "...can select some lines..." 
I know about the "find and replace".
Do you offer to do this for each file and each line every time?
It is a good solution for this goal?

Comment: if you don't find options in axblack and similar then it can be the only option. And you didn't say how much file you want to format - for few lines it can be easy solution. But you can also get source code of `axblack` and block some functions in code to create tool which fit to you.

Comment: @furas. Yes, I did. I checked axblack documentation. I didn't see how to disable all functions except only one by yourself. Yes, I agree, that rewrite sources or write tool is a variant, but it is an extreme option.